# Show selected value in discord.ui.Select after reloading view

Tags: python, discord.py

i am writing a bot with discord py and have the following problem:

My view has two select lists. Based on the selection in the first select, the values in the second are set dynamically. For this I use the function message.edit(view=view). This works fine, i got the selected value in a variable. But the select is resetting the option, and shows the placeholder.

This is my code:

```
class view_admin_card(discord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        print('ping')
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.card_options = []
        self.db = WizDB()
        self.options = []
        fractions = self.db.get_all_fractions()

        for f in fractions:
            x = discord.SelectOption(
                label=f[1],
                value=f[1]
            )
            self.options.append(x)
        for elem in self.children:
            if elem.custom_id == 'fraction':
                elem.options = self.options

    # async def disable_items(self):
    #     for item in self.children:
    #         item.disabled = True
    #     await self.message.edit(view=self)

    # async def on_timeout(self) -> None:
    #     await self.message.add_reaction('⚠️')
    #     await self.disable_items()

    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Bitte Fraktion wählen",
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1,
        custom_id='fraction',
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="1",
                value="1"
            )
        ]
    )
    async def test(
        self,
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        select: discord.ui.Select
    ):
        self.card_options = []
        self.selectedFraction = str(select.values[0])
        for elem in self.children:
            if elem.custom_id == 'cards':
                # if str(elem.type) == 'ComponentType.button':
                cards = self.db.get_cards_by_fraction(self.selectedFraction)
                for c in cards:
                    x = discord.SelectOption(
                        label=c[1],
                        value=c[0]
                    )
                    self.card_options.append(x)
                elem.options = self.card_options
                elem.disabled = False
            elif str(elem.type) == 'ComponentType.button':
                elem.disabled = True
        await self.message.edit(view=self)
        await interaction.response.defer()

    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Bitte Einheit wählen",
        custom_id='cards',
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1,
        disabled=True,
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="1",
                value="1"
            )
        ]
    )
    async def test2(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        self.selectedCard = str(select.values[0])
        for elem in self.children:
            if str(elem.type) == 'ComponentType.button':
                elem.disabled = False
        await interaction.response.defer()
```

Could someone help me how to show the selected value after editing the message?

Best Regards,
Dennis

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the problem, but instead of editing the message and then deferring the interaction, why aren't you just using `await interaction.response.edit_message()`? This method will edit the message and respond to interaction